# HPCC/HDFS Connector

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, hpcc

Does anyone know about HPCC/HDFS connector.we are using both HPCC and HADOOP.There is one utility(HPCC/HDFS connector) developed by HPCC which allows HPCC cluster to acess HDFS data

i have installed the connector but when i run the program to acess data from hdfs it gives error as libhdfs.so.0 doesn't exist.

I tried to build libhdfs.so using command

```
 ant compile-libhdfs -Dlibhdfs=1
```

its giving me error as

> target "compile-libhdfs"  does not exist in the project "hadoop"

i used one more command

```
 ant compile-c++-libhdfs -Dlibhdfs=1
```

its giving error as

> ivy-download:
>
> ```
>   [get] Getting: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.1.0/ivy-2.1.0.jar
>
>   [get] To: /home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/ivy/ivy-2.1.0.jar
>
>   [get] Error getting http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.1.0/ivy-2.1.0.jar
> ```
>
> to /home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/ivy/ivy-2.1.0.jar
>
> BUILD FAILED java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out

any suggestion will be a great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chhaya, you might not need to build libhdfs.so, depending on how you installed hadoop, you might already have it.

Check in `HADOOP_LOCATION/c++/Linux-<arch>/lib/libhdfs.so`, where `HADOOP_LOCATION` is your hadoop install location, and `arch` is the machine’s architecture (i386-32 or amd64-64).

Once you locate the lib, make sure the H2H connector is configured correctly ([see page 4 here](http://cdn.hpccsystems.com/install/docs/3_8_0_4rc_CE/HDFS_to_HPCC_Connector.pdf)).

It's just a matter of updating the `HADOOP_LOCATION` var in the config file:
`/opt/HPCCSystems/hdfsconnector.conf`

good luck.

Comment: i updated HADOOP_LOCATION as /home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0 then to its giving same error.We are having HPCC on one machine and hadoop on another machine is this the problem ? .libhdfs.so is there in  HADOOP_LOCATION/c++/Linux-<arch>/lib/libhdfs.so but am facing same problem while running program

Comment: the H2H connector requires hadoop 1.x, looks like you have hadoop 0.2 beta... Also your hadoop system and the HPCC system don't need to be running on the same machines, but the H2H connector needs to have the libhdfs.so locally available.

Comment: btw, the H2H connector's logs can be found here: /var/log/HPCCSystems/mydataconnectors/HDFSCONNECTOR.*.log once you get the correct version of hadoop's hdfslib I'd be interested to see what the latest log shows...

Comment: hi..is there any document for the same which shows which version is required foe H2H...i read the log also there only i got this error

Comment: libhdfs should be locally available means i shld install libhdfs on ma HPCC cluster?

Comment: Yes, the H2H connector is dependent on hadoop v1+ and should be installed on each HPCC node.

Comment: didnt get you whether i should install libhdfs on each HPCC node or H2H on each node